# I receive a KeyError: 'main' when run a request through openWeather APIs

Tags: flask, openweathermap

I am getting a `KeyError: 'main'` when I run this flask code in which I want a result that will not be printed through the terminal but returned in the web browser. This is my code that runs the rest to the open weather API

```py
from wap import app
from flask import render_template, request
import requests
import json

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_app():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        city = request.form['city']
        country = request.form['country']
        api_key = '#########################'

        weather_url = requests.get(
            f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid={api_key} &q=city{city},{country} &units=metric'
        )

        weather_data = weather_url.json()

        temp = round(weather_data['main']['temp'])
        humidity = weather_data['main']['humidity']
        wind_speed = weather_data['wind']['speed']

        return render_template('result.html', temp=temp, humidity=humidity, wind_speed=wind_speed, city=city)
    return render_template('index.html')
```

The error occurs when I need to the temp, humidity, or wind.

Comment: Fix the spacing in `?appid={api_key} &q=city{city},{country} &units=metric` - there's not supposed to be spaces before the ampersands. Then be sure to `from pprint import pprint` then `pprint (weather_data)` and ensure what looks like the correct API response prints in your terminal when this endpoint is hit.

Answer (score 0):

that error means that you tried to retrieve a key that didn't exist in the dict.

First, inspect data of the response. Many APIs answer with some nested JSON like `{"data": { actualdata} }` or the likes. So you might have to do an extra step to get to main.

Also, the call was probably wrong because the spaces, as @v25 pointed out. And the answer might be something like `{"error": "Wrong query"}` or something like that, where there is no "main" key

If the problem is becuase the API is temporally down and you don,t want your program to fail you could use .get, along these lines:

```
temp  = weather_data.get("main", {}).get("temp")
```